# How to add durability to an archive?

Tags: windows-7, archiving

I have a collection of home videos I want to archive on Amazon Glacier.  Since Glacier has a 4 Gb file limit, I need to split some of my 4Gb+ files in to smaller chunks.  I figured I should add some protective measures to those file chunks (e.g. CRC).

Can anyone recommend a Windows 7 compatible tool that can chunk up and restore a large file with the ability to add some durability to protect against corruption?

Comment: Try winrar, I think it adds some kind of measures to the compressed files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using a non-free tool, WinRAR has a [recovery record](http://www.win-rar.com/faq.html?&L=0#c1425) option you can apply to your archives. The recovery record makes your archive bigger than it would be otherwise, but allows you to recovery from minor corruption to the archive data.

If you're looking for something free, or have your heart set on using another archive format, you can look into [PAR2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive), which is basically a recovery record format that can be used with arbitrary files.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Glacier (at least if used over native Amazon Glacier API) does not have 4Gb file limit.

http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/

> Individual archives are limited to a maximum size of 40 terabytes.

So perhaps the limit that you see is limitation of you client.